# Word press plugin is gone?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

So I am just your typical level 2 IT guy, not web developer no matter what marketing says. My company had a word press google map plugin installed with about 200 location markers. This morning marketing called and said the map was gone. When I go to the website it shows [put_wpgm id=2] where the map used to be and the plugin is gone? Does anyone have any idea what I should do? Do the plugins save their data somewhere? Did it delete itself because it was out of date? Please help :/

Comment: [put_wpgm id=2] is a shortcode, check the plugin section in administration and see if there is some problem with the plugin that controls the maps

Comment: That's the thing the plugin for the map is gone? It said that it was deactivated but when I go to inactive plugins it is not there.

Comment: then investigate what happened to your plugin or reinstall it and everithing will work again

Comment: If I reinstall it will it remap all the locations? there are like 200+ location markers that I don't know how I will set back up

Comment: It should. Unless somebody didn't delete the data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you where using Advanced Google Maps Plugin for Wordpress from Envato. Re-install the plugin and everything will work again with the old data.

Comment: Hey thanks. I am searching for Envato under author for plugins and I don't see anything coming up? I also searched google maps Envato but no luck.

Comment: If it came from Envato, then you probably have to go to https://market.envato.com, track down your login information (from whoever bought the plugin originally) and download it from there again. I don't suppose you have a backup anywhere? If so, you could probably just download the plugin from your backup, reinstall it in the plugins directory, and reactivate.

Comment: Hey Greg, Thats a great idea I just got a backup of the website. How should I go about restoring the plugin from backup?

Comment: Open up the backup and head to wp-content/plugins -- in there you should see a folder with all of the plugin files. not sure what that folder would be called, but you should be able to guess based on the the plugin name "Advanced Google Maps". Copy that folder to your website, same location (wp-content/plugins). You should now be able to go into wp-admin, click Plugins, and activate the plugin again. Should fix things if no one messed with the database of locations somehow...

Comment: Hey Greg. That worked amazingly. Except now when the map is active the website sits at a black spinning screen :( more problems ><

Comment: Looks like still some work to do but we figured out the plugins at least! thanks guys